# Do I have a rod kncking in my 2001 Ford Fusion?

Tags: engine, ford, noise, fusion

I have a 2011 Ford Fusion with 108,000 miles.  I have the oil change every 3-4 thousand miles.  It has always made a clicking sound but seems louder over the last couple months.  Also, when I step on the gas it hesitates until I get to about 35 mph.  Sometimes it will jerk a little when I step on the gas on the initial take off.  I took it to trade it in and they said just by listening that I have a rod knocking.  I find this hard to believe since it has been making the clicking noise for a couple months.  What else could this be?

Comment: I'd be unable to give a closer punt compared to this mechanic who checked it, I don't have any audio. If you were able to upload a video on YouTube of the engine running, revving and idling at operating temperature, I'd be able to give a fairly accurate guess. 
It could either be con-rods, timing chain/chain tensioners (them ford fusions are terrible for that) or perhaps something else in the engine bay loose, but if the mechanic says it's a rod, I'd probably go with what he said. If he does con-rods and it doesn't fix the problem, take it back and ask for reimbursal.

Comment: Also, could I ask if this is 2001 or 2011? Change either the title or the question to fix this error.